# splitting whitespaces doesn't work fine

Tags: java, regex, split, whitespace

I have searched a lot about regex and finally I found out that it's better to use "\\s+" for splitting a string
But amazingly it doesn't anything to the original String:

```
private static void process(String command) {
    command = command.substring(0, command.length() - 1);
    String[] splitted = command.split("\\s+");
    for (String str : splitted) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

sample input:

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(true);
```

preferred output:

```
[Boolean,b,=,new,Boolean(true)]
```

But my method output is :

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(true)
```

Comment: What's your question? What's your input, expected output and actual output for this method?

Comment: If you want parse arguments in the command line, check http://commons.apache.org/cli/

Comment: I used    substring for removing the ';' from my String

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Please be specific about your intent.

Comment: There's no way your actual output is generated by the code in your question (it would print one line for each array element). If you expect `String command` to be different after invoking `process()` on it, note that strings in Java are immutable, everything you do to it stays in `process()`.

Comment: `command = command.substring(0, command.length() - 1);`  That seems equivalent to 'do nothing'.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson : it will remove the last character, but my problem is not there!

Comment: Your code works exactly as it should; it prints each 'word' on a new line. If you're expecting brackets and commas then you have to insert that in your output. There doesn't seem to be a problem here, unless you mis-specified what you're looking for?

Comment: What's the value of `splitted.length`?

Comment: -1 on the question. The code and sample output do not match up. That said @Tim Pote has given the answer you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that "preferred output" use `Arrays.toString(splitted)`.  Your code, however, works like it's supposed to.  It prints each element of the array on a new line.  So this code:

```
  private static void process(String command) {
    command = command.substring(0, command.length() - 1);

    String[] splitted = command.split("\\s+");

    for (String str : splitted) {
      System.out.println(str);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted).replace(" ", ""));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    process("Boolean b = new Boolean(true); ");
  }
```

Produces this output:

```
Boolean
b
=
new
Boolean(true);
[Boolean, b, =, new, Boolean(true);]
```

Note that the `substring` operation doesn't work like you want because of the trailing spaces in your input string.  You can use `command.trim()` beforehand to get rid of any leading/trailing spaces.

***Edit***

I edited my code, because, as @Tim Bender says, there are spaces between array elements in the output of `Arrays.toString` and that's not exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: I replaced exactly your method with the one that I said, but the output was not what you said!

Comment: Add my `main` method to that class, run it, and tell me what you get.

Comment: You probably should have posted your `main` (or at least the relevant part of it) to begin with.  We knew all along that your sample input and output were off.  Go ahead and post it and I'll take a look.